# Facebook BOT Webhook integration

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, bots, messenger

Trying to set up webhook for Facebook app, I got error:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="1786621504", received="\t\t\n1786621504{\"resul..."

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMaUk.png)

Here is the code from `index.php`. The same code works perfectly on another facebook app.

In `request1.txt` I checked logs and it looks like this:

> 1478271548{"hub_mode":"subscribe","hub_challenge":"1786621504","hub_verify_token":"my_password"}

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
$access_token ="token_here";

$verify_token = "my_password";
$hub_verify_token = "my_password";
fwrite ( $fl, json_encode($_REQUEST));
if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['hub_challenge'] )) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST ['hub_challenge'];
    $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST ['hub_verify_token'];
}
$fl = fopen ( "request.txt", "a" );
 fwrite ( $fl, json_encode($_REQUEST));


$fh = fopen ( "/testbot/log.txt", "a" );

if ($hub_verify_token === "my_password") {
    echo $challenge;//exit;
}
```

Comment: Do not post the secret keys and access tokens here!

Comment: you write to a file `$fl` and after that you define the file... That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['hub_mode']) && $_REQUEST['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe') 
{
    echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
}
```